# How to call two controllers in one controller folder when using hmvc CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have the following folder structure

```
Modules
    --controllers
        --User
        --Product
```

How can I call the product controller from user controller from one particular function?

When I run this url `http://[::1]/stagingweb/index.php/user/product` I get the error 'The page you requested was not found'.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I noticed your ip in the url. Latest versions of codeigniter it is recommended to set the base url as some of your css and other links will not work.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have a problem to understand the concept of hmvc here

HMVC stands for **Hierarchical model–view–controller**, which means in Wiredesignz HMVC there is an additional variation called `modules` added to the classical **MVC** pattern used by Codeigniter.

in your case if you have `users` and `products`, its probably the best to create 2 modules (users and products).

So your folder structure would look like

```
modules
    - users
        - controllers
            User.php
        - models
        - views

    - products
        - controllers
            Product.php
        - models
        - views
```

in Wiredesignz HMVC Integration there is a class `MX_Controller`, so every module controller has to extend from it.

an example

```
class Product extends MX_Controller{}
```

And if you want to call another modules controller within your specific controller you simply have to call

`$return = modules::run('products/product/your_function');`

Though in most cases it's probably a cleaner solution to just call the models from the other modules instead of executing a controllers function...

> The entire process is very well documented [here](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/overview)

Comment: What about if you have same controllers for frontend and admin panel. For example

This one replicates all of your frontend functionalities

    modules
    -- Article

This one replicates all of your backend functionalities

    modules
    -- Admin
    --- Articles

Comment: to be honest i don't understand what you mean. What did you replicate in first place ? And what's your issue ?